# Android xml parsing

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I need detailed tutorial or example on Xml-Parsing In Android

Answer (score 5):

You can check out this post...

They would have nicely discussed all 3 kinds of parsers available in Android along with code samples

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You parse XML on Android just like you would do it in regular Java. You have both [`org.w3c.dom`](http://d.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html) and [`org.xml.sax`](http://d.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/package-summary.html) packages available in Android. Use the one that best fits your needs, there are plenty of tutorials for both of them available on the Internet.

Answer (score -1):

1. Getting XML content by making HTTP Request

   ```
   public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
       String xml = null;

       try {
           // defaultHttpClient
           DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

           HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
           HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
           xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

       } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       // return XML
       return xml;
   }
   ```
2. Parsing XML content and getting DOM element

   ```
   public Document getDomElement(String xml) {
       Document doc = null;
       DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
       try {

           DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

           InputSource is = new InputSource();
               is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
               doc = db.parse(is);

           } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
               Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
               return null;
           } catch (SAXException e) {
               Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
               return null;
           } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
               return null;
           }
               // return DOM
           return doc;
       }
   ```
3. Get each xml child element value by passing element node name

   ```
   public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
       NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
       return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
   }

   public final String getElementValue(Node elem) {
       Node child;
       if (elem != null) {
           if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
               for (child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()) {
                   if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                       return child.getNodeValue();
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       return "";
   }
   ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.