# Android XML Parsing link error

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-xml, android-parser

I have an xml file generated dynamically through a php code section.I need this xml file to be read inside my android application.Can anybody suggest a method for the same?

The xml file just looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<Buyer>
<buyerId>27</buyerId>
<name>321</name>
<country>Albania</country>
<emailId>1@gmail.com</emailId>
<password>444</password>
<address>234
</address>
<city>33</city>
<state>333</state>
<zip>2222</zip>
<phone>33</phone>
<accountstatus>1</accountstatus>
<userType>buyer</userType>
</Buyer>
</Root>
```

Comment: how you tried before ask question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827344/how-to-parse-xml-using-the-sax-parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/ that is a great starter for parsing XML. They mention a couple of different ways.

Another simple example: 
http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html

Otherwise check out these answers: 
[ANDROID: Parsing XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839372/android-parsing-xml)

[Android: Best XML Parsing Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926367/android-best-xml-parsing-library)

[Android xml parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492034/android-xml-parsing)